# How do I make Vim wait indefinitely after leader key has been pressed?

Tags: vimrc

I'm trying to make Vim wait after the leader key indefinitely without messing with the `timeoutlen` of other keys.
Currently I have this lines in my vimrc:

```
let mapleader=" "
set timeoutlen=2000 ttimeoutlen=0
```

Setting `ttimeoutlen` make commands such as `ciw` last permanently.

The Spacemacs plugin for Emacs which has a nice set of default configurations, one of these is that the leader key waits indefinitely. Can I do this on Vim by any other way than changing the `timeoutlen` values?

Comment: What do you mean by makeing the key persistent? Isn't it persistent, once you put this in your .vimrc?

Comment: Sorry, I mean last longer. For example, in my case if I start type in normal mode "<leader>..." , the command only last for 2 seconds. What I want is Vim wait for the entire command or until I press ESC.

Comment: You mean the timeout? Does `:h 'timout'` help you?

Comment: Not much, since I can't found anything about key specific timeout. (I want just the leader key to wait the command)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a dirty workaround you could consider:

```
" Increase timeoutlen when <Leader> is pressed
" Only one of these lines is needed.  I am not sure which is most recommended.
"nmap <silent> <Leader> :<C-U>set timeoutlen=99999 ttimeoutlen=99999<CR><Leader>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader> :<C-U>set timeoutlen=99999 ttimeoutlen=99999<CR>:call feedkeys('<Leader>')<CR>

" Reset timeoutline to normal soon afterwards
autocmd CursorMoved * set timeoutlen=2000 ttimeoutlen=0
```

The CursorMoved event is not ideal but it usually gets triggered sooner or later.  You may be able to find other events or mappings to reset the values in those cases when you get stuck on the long timeout.

Answer (score 3):

If you do `:set notimeout nottimeout` mappings won't time out. This is all explained very well at `:h 'timeout'`
You might try other combinations of those two mappings.

Comment: I think the OP wants to set the timeout options for specific keys.  _(such as making only the leader key not time out)_